# How to render value from mysql database in ejs template

Tags: javascript, mysql

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
con.query('SELECT sum(price) FROM sales', function(err, result, fields){
res.render('index.ejs',{amount:result});
});
});
```

The above code is for app.js in which i want to render in ejs template to display the result value.

```
<%= amount %>
```

above is for the index.ejs and the out put shows {object}{object}. Please i need help to render it correctly
Thanks

Comment: Try this: `SELECT sum(price) as total FROM sales` and `res.render('index.ejs',{amount:result.total});`

Comment: Thanks for ur quick responds sir, unfortunately nothing displayed. empty

Comment: console.log(result); gave this print out  [RowDataPacket{total:395174778 }]

Comment: <%for (var i=0; i<amount.length; i++){ %>
<%= amount[i].total %>
<% } %>

Answer (score 0):

index.ejs

```
<%for (var i=0; i<amount.length; i++){ %> 
<%= amount[i].total %> 
<% } %>
```